# Passing bash shell variable to jq filter

Tags: bash, shell, jq

Trying to pass a bash shell variable into a jq filter

JSON:

```
{
"server1": {
"port": 3333,
"name": "foo",
"timesincelast": 248054
},
"server2": {
"port": 4444,
"name": "bar",
"timesincelast": 248054
  }
  }
```

Bash command trying to execute:

```
 servername='server1'
 jq --arg servername "$servername" '.$servername .port'
```

But getting an error

```
 jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '$' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at 
<top-level>, line 1:
```

But direct substitution works

```
jq '.server1 .port'
```

Comment: Nope..  didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write:

```
.[$servername] | .port
```

or simply:

```
.[$servername].port
```

Comment: You just saved my sanity... thank you so much, I have tried .{$servername}.port but it gave the same error