# bash filename as parameter in jq commands

Tags: bash, shell, command-substitution

Here is the bash function to parse a json file use 'jq' command:

```
jq_fullpath_endkey() {
      PATHARRAY=$(jq -c 'paths | select(.[-1] == "'$keyword'")|map(strings |= ".\(.)" | numbers |= "[\(.)]") | join("")' **${news.json}**)
}
```

The `news.json` is the json file that contains all the content I'd like to parse with jq.

The function works once I replace `${news.json}` with a variable named `response` which contains `news.json` content as string.

Below is the command which works:

```
  PATHARRAY=$(jq -c 'paths | select(.[-1] == "'$keyword'")|map(strings |= ".\(.)" | numbers |= "[\(.)]") | join("")'**<<< "$response"**)
```

My question is how can I use 'json file' as part of the jq cmd ?
I suspect there is something wrong with double/single quote I am using.

Comment: Are you passing the filename as a parameter to the function (i.e. `jq_fullpath_endkey news.json`)? If so, just use `"$1"` in the command. BTW, the way you're injecting `$keyword` is not recommended -- use `--arg` instead (see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52959216/passing-bash-shell-variable-to-jq-filter)).

Comment: yes, it works :)  , I am using "parameter substitution" and it works also. thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out with "[parameter substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html)" in bash

```
myfile="news.json"
PATHARRAY=$(jq -c 'paths | select(.[-1] == "'$keyword'")|map(strings |= ".\(.)" | numbers |= "[\(.)]") | join("")' ${myfile})
```

Related concepts:
[variable substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html)
[command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)

Comment: This works as long the variables _myfile_ and _keyword_ contain neither spaces nor wildcard (glob) characters.