# How do I pass a list of filenames from find to jq?

Tags: bash, jq

The command `find . -name 'reddit.*.flattened.json' | jq '.'` gives the error `parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0`.

Motivated by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52959216/passing-bash-shell-variable-to-jq-filter), I tried `jq --arg`.

But, `find . -name 'reddit.*.flattened.json' | jq --arg filename $1 '. $filename'` gives the same error.

Output of `find` query:

```
./reddit.opiates.flattened.json
./reddit.OurOverUsedVeins.flattened.json
./reddit.microdosing.flattened.json
./reddit.naloxone.flattened.json
./reddit.suboxone.flattened.json
./reddit.heroin.flattened.json
./reddit.OpiatesRecovery.flattened.json
./reddit.fentanyl.flattened.json
```

I can load each file with `jq` by typing `jq '.' FILENAME` so there is no error in the files.

Comment: Are you looking for `xargs`? `… | xargs jq '.'`

Comment: `find ... -exec jq . {} +`?

Comment: If all those files are in a single dir (no depth needed), why not use a the 'search' directly `jq 'filter' reddit.*.flattened.json`

Comment: Originally I used xargs and it gave them error. But then I realized I typed `find ... | xargs jq` rather than `find ... | xargs jq '.'`. The latter command works.

Comment: @0stone0 nice alternate solution!

Comment: If you would see this as a valid answer @mac389, please let me know so I can post it.

Comment: Note that your solution above is a bit buggy. `find ... -exec jq . {} +` or `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 jq .` is better. Note the `-0` on the xargs side and `-print0` on the find side, it's important to handle unusual filenames, which xargs fails at by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let `find` do it, instead of having the shell stick its nose in the middle.

```
find . -name 'reddit.*.flattened.json' -exec jq '.' {} \;
```

This avoids issues with names that contain any whitespace (and especially names that contain newline characters) or glob metacharacters.

(For most filters and combinations of arguments, you can safely reduce the number of times `jq` is called by letting it read from multiple files per invocation with

```
find ... -exec jq '.' {} +
```

)

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you

> can load each file with jq by typing jq '.' FILENAME

you could use the anti-pattern:

```
jq . $(find ……)
```

However you would have to be a bit more ingenious to handle more tricky filenames. See e.g. solutions proposed in comments by @CharlesDuffy, [How do I store the output from a find command in an array? + bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34983843/how-do-i-store-the-output-from-a-find-command-in-an-array-bash), etc etc.

Comment: boo, hiss re: showcasing a major antipattern (see [BashPitfalls #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29))

Comment: (really do feel entirely free to fold any suggestions I make in the comments or elsewhere into the answer itself)

Comment: Good to know. Likewise, feel free to improve my responses. In this case I was mainly trying to point out the muddle.